# do is anyway to detect Tablets Pills package is empty or not?

Tags: infrared, packages, detector

do infrared sensor can pass through transparent plastic and work?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just use your eyes is my advice or, if you are a little visually impaired ask someone to help.

Comment: There are two ways to answer this question: try it yourself, or look up the IR absorption spectra of the types of plastic used in this kind of packaging.

Comment: Probably, but don't rule out the possibility of remains of the foil backing and/or distortion of the plastic bubble providing some occlusion.  Another direction to the apparent problem to consider could be computer vision, ie, webcam and OpenCV, first on a PC later on an embedded Linux board.

Comment: @Chris Stratton thank you, do Is there another cheap way Except infrared? camera and OpenCV is expensive

Comment: Actually webcams and computing power are pretty cheap; presumably to do it with IR sensors you are going to need a bunch of them and fixturing; you can probably prototype with a 3d printer but then you'll need mold tooling...  Granted the vision approach has alignment and lighting challenges so there are tradeoffs all around.

Comment: @ChrisStratton ok I understood , thank you

Comment: Why don't you make an app for your phone? Phone cameras are cheap, it wouldn't be to unreasonable to make a simple image detection program to detect whether the package is white or not.

Comment: @VoltageSpike because i want to place it in Tablets Pills packaging machine and 6*6 or 6*4  infrared sensor is cheapest way

Comment: You should have mentioned this is for the packaging stage, your photo misleadingly makes it look like you are talking about monitoring usage.  Computer vision inspection sounds like a plausible idea, or maybe even weighing it, but I'd suspect you have some fairly serious *legal* requirements for your quality control that go well beyond getting random advice here - this really needs to be a conversation with your compliance department in the loop if not guiding it.

Comment: https://userweb.cs.txstate.edu/~br02/cs1428/ShortStoryForEngineers.htm

Comment: And transmissive IR would be useless in a packaging machine as the foil would block it regardless if there was a tablet in the pouch or not.  You could do it before adding the foil, but that doesn't catch one falling out before the foil is applied.  And it doesn't catch broken ones, such as clearly visible in your picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your eyes cannot see IR but your (phone) camera can!

Grab your TV remote as an IR source and while pressing a button on the remote look at the remote through your phone's camera (actually almost any digital camera will do).

Chances are you will see the IR transmitter LED in the TV remote flashing like so:

[image]

Now hold the pills package in between and check if you can still see the IR LED flashing.

If yes: then the IR light can pass through the holes in the package.

However, the aluminium (?) foil in the pills package will block IR very effectively. If that foil is not removed then the IR light will not pass through.

Only if there is a clear visible hole left (through which you can see light pass through) can this work reliably as a pill present/not present detector.

Comment: thank you, do Is there another cheap way Except infrared?

Comment: @user8591 Welcome to Stack Exchange! If you have a second question, you should [create another question post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead of posting your second question as a comment.

Comment: @TannerSwett thank you , ok

Comment: Some brands of phone cameras can not see IR.

Comment: That is true, Apple devices tend to have fairly good IR filters; sometimes "cheaper is better" a budget webcam is likely very susceptible.